# c++. placing points on straight lines

Tags: c++, c++17

In one of the largest cities in Bytland, Bytesburg, construction of the second stage of the metro is underway. During the construction of the first stage, N stations were built that were not interconnected. According to the master plan, the metro in Bytesburg should consist of no more than two lines. each metro line is straight. The president of the company responsible for laying the lines wants to make sure that no more than two metro lines can be laid, so that all stations built lie on at least one of the two

Exaple 1
input:

```
6 
0 1 
1 1 
2 1 
0 2 
1 3 
2 2
```

output:

```
no
```

Example 2
input:

```
6
2 2
4 6
1 0
2 1
6 1
1 1
```

output:

```
yes
```

I wrote the code, but on the seventh test on the testing system, it gives the wrong answer. Help me please. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;



struct line {
    int k, b;
    bool x = false;
    long long c = 0;
};

int n;
vector<line> lines;
vector<pair<int, int>> p;

bool Is3PointsOnLine(pair<float, float> p1, pair<float, float> p2, pair<float, float> p3) {
    return ((p3.first - p1.first)*(p2.second - p1.second) == (p3.second - p1.second)*(p2.first - p1.first));
}

bool PointIsOnLine(line l, int x, int y) {
    if (!l.x) {
        if (y == ((l.k * x) + l.b))
            return true;
    }
    else {
        if (x == l.b)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}


line f(pair<int, int> c1, pair<int, int> c2) {
    int x1 = c1.first;
    int y1 = c1.second;
    int x2 = c2.first;
    int y2 = c2.second;

    line ans;
    if (x2 != x1) {
        ans.k = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);//fix
        ans.b = -(x1 * y2 - x1 * y1 - x2 * y1 + x1 * y1) / (x2 - x1);
        ans.x = false;
        ans.c = 0;
    }
    else {
        ans.k = 0;      
        ans.b = x1;
        ans.x = true;
        ans.c = 0;
    }

    return ans;
}

int a() {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (j != i) {
                for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                    if ((k != i) && (k != j) && (Is3PointsOnLine(p[i], p[j], p[k]))) {
                        lines.push_back(f(p[i], p[j]));
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {    
    cin >> n;
    p.resize(n);

    vector<int> not_used;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> p[i].first >> p[i].second;
    
    if (n < 5) {
        cout << "yes";
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        a();

        if (lines.size() == 0) {
            cout << "no";
            return 0;
        }

        pair<int, int> e = { -8,-8 };               

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (PointIsOnLine(lines[0], p[i].first, p[i].second)) {
                lines[0].c++;
            }
            else if (e.first == -8) {
                e.first = i;
            }
            else if (e.second == -8) {
                e.second = i;
                lines.push_back(f(p[e.first], p[e.second]));

                for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                    if (PointIsOnLine(lines[1], p[j].first, p[j].second)) {
                        lines[1].c++;
                    }
                }

                e = { -5,-5 };
            }
            else if (PointIsOnLine(lines[1], p[i].first, p[i].second)) {
                lines[1].c++;
            }
            else {
                cout << "no";
                return 0;
            }
        }   
        
        if (lines[0].c+1 >= n && e.first != -2 && e.second == -8) {
            cout << "yes";
            return 0;
        }       
        else if (lines[0].c + lines[1].c >= n) {
            cout << "yes";
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            cout << "no";
            return 0;
        }
        
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

Code v2

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct line {
    pair<int, int> p1, p2;
    long long c = 0;
};

int n;
vector<line> lines;
vector<pair<int, int>> p;

bool Is3PointsOnLine(pair<float, float> p1, pair<float, float> p2, pair<float, float> p3) {
    return ((p3.first - p1.first)*(p2.second - p1.second) == (p3.second - p1.second)*(p2.first - p1.first));
}

//лежит ли точка на прямой
bool PointIsOnLine(line l, int x, int y) {
    return Is3PointsOnLine(l.p1, l.p2, {x , y});
}

int a() {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (j != i) {
                for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                    if ((k != i) && (k != j) && (Is3PointsOnLine(p[i], p[j], p[k]))) {
                        line sdafsadf;
                        sdafsadf.p1 = p[i]; sdafsadf.p2 = p[j];
                        lines.push_back(sdafsadf);
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {    
    cin >> n;
    p.resize(n);

    vector<int> not_used;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> p[i].first >> p[i].second;
    
    if (n < 5) {
        cout << "yes";
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        //ищем первую прямую
        a();

        if (lines.size() == 0) {
            cout << "no";
            return 0;
        }

        pair<int, int> e = { -8,-8 };               

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (PointIsOnLine(lines[0], p[i].first, p[i].second)) {
                lines[0].c++;
            }
            else if (e.first == -8) {
                e.first = i;
            }
            else if (e.second == -8) {
                e.second = i;

                line sdafsadf;
                sdafsadf.p1 = p[e.first]; sdafsadf.p2 = p[e.second];
                lines.push_back(sdafsadf);

                for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                    if (PointIsOnLine(lines[1], p[j].first, p[j].second)) {
                        lines[1].c++;
                    }
                }

                e = { -5,-5 };
            }
            else if (PointIsOnLine(lines[1], p[i].first, p[i].second)) {
                lines[1].c++;
            }
            else {
                cout << "no";
                return 0;
            }
        }   
        
        if (lines[0].c+1 >= n && e.first != -2 && e.second == -8) {
            cout << "yes";
            return 0;
        }       
        else if ((lines[0].c + lines[1].c >= n) && (lines[0].p1 != lines[1].p1) && (lines[0].p1 != lines[1].p2) && (lines[0].p2 != lines[1].p1) && (lines[0].p2 != lines[1].p2)) {
            cout << "yes";
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            cout << "no";
            return 0;
        }
        
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does your current code output?

Comment: Your current implementation appears to be O(N^3)  I am convinced this is possible in O(N^2).

Comment: @GalaxyCat105, My current code correctly answers the tests I provided in the question text. But on the 7th test, it gives the wrong answer, what data is displayed - I don't know

Comment: I also tried to do it through iteration of lines for the first three points, but I realized that this would not work correctly when all n points should lie on two parallel lines. I tried the same thing, but with four points, the testing system gave an error on test 5.

Comment: @Ben Voigt, Perhaps, but so far there has not been a problem with time yet, but there has already been an incorrect answer, it means that somewhere in my code there is an error

Comment: That's why my feedback on the complexity was a comment not an answer.

Comment: Have you tested on the case where there is a large number of stations, and a single line is sufficient to reach all of them?

Comment: @Ben Voigt, yes, I checked. In this case, my program works. 10
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 7
8 8
9 9
10 10
yes

Answer (score 0):

Your function `f` is horribly broken because it uses integer division.  Then everything after that which relies on `k` and `b`, including `PointIsOnLine`, will give wrong results.  `Is3PointsOnLine` seems ok, change your `line` struct to store two points, not slope+intercept, and then `PointInOnLine` can just call `Is3PointsOnLine`.

I'm amazed that you passed any non-trivial test cases with such a bug.

This also will not work

```
if (lines[0].c + lines[1].c >= n)
```

because you aren't testing that `lines[1]` isn't a duplicate of `lines[0]`.

Also, you can reach `lines[0].c + lines[1].c == n` and still miss one station completely, if another station lies at the intersection of the lines and gets double-counted.

Comment: I changed as you said. But now my code only passes 4 tests. I added code to the question - Code v2. What is the mistake now?

Comment: @asdfjsldfksjdsdjklas: If you find that `lines[1]` is a duplicate of `lines[0]` (and your test for that is wrong anyway) then you still need to find the first line that *isn't* a duplicate of `lines[0]`.  Also, the number of points on the two lines could be `n` if the lines don't intersect on a station, or `n+1` if they DO intersect on a station...  But if the two lines DO intersect on a station and then both miss one station, you will get `n` which still passes your `>= n` test.  You can't just look at the count of points on your two lines, you have to check that every point is on a line.

Comment: I think I need to declare a vector in the structure where the points that lie on this line will be stored. At the end, we need to add them into one vector and translate them into a set, then we can find out how many points we used. Am I thinking right?